# Using static objects in custom keyword methods for katalon

Tags: katalon-studio

As per Katalon documentation https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/handling-databases.html

Database connection string is static

```
private static Connection connection = null;
```

This is will be used for creating, Querying and closing the connection. Using custom keyword feature of Katalon, these methods will be called.

```
CustomKeywords.'dataProvider.MySQL.connectDB'()
```

With a single test case, this is fine. What will happen for parallel execution. Will the connection object be shared across all the threads and it cause some other problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a standalone keyword for each testcase to implement different `executeQuery()` methods and to execute different `SQL` query strings.